# Error " formal parameter "G" is not referenced "

Tags: parameters, ada

I get the error message "parsing.adb:22:32: warning: formal parameter "G" is not referenced "
when I compile my code. Any idea what I have to change not to get this error message ?

here's my code:

```
with Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO, Life, parsing;
use Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO, Life, parsing;

package body Parsing is

Parsing_Failed : exception;


type New_Grid is record
Hauteur : Natural;
Largeur : Natural;
Tableau : Grid;
end record;

   procedure Grid_Load_LIF(G : out Grid ; File_Name : in String) is
    Fichier:File_Type;
    Ligne:String(1..75);
    Grille : New_Grid;
    Num_Ligne : Positive := 1;
    Lu : Natural:=0;
begin
open(Fichier, In_File, File_Name);

while not End_of_File(Fichier) loop
    get_Line(Fichier, Ligne, Lu);

for i in 1..Lu loop
    if ligne(I) = '*' then
        grille.Tableau(Num_Ligne,I) := True;
    elsif ligne(I)= '.' then
        grille.Tableau(Num_Ligne,I) := False;

    end if;
end loop;
Num_Ligne := Num_Ligne +1;
grille.Largeur := Lu;
grille.Hauteur := Num_Ligne;

end loop;
end Grid_Load_LIF;

end Parsing;
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Well you need to do _something_ with that parameter, or remove it from the parameters if you don't need it.

Comment: where are you using this procedure?

Comment: @Mat what do you mean remove it from parameters ( i'm all new with ada ! )

Comment: @Ash I'm using it to open a .lif file in another predure

Comment: `procedure Grid_Load_LIF(G : out Grid ; File_Name : in String) is` This says your function takes a string and "returns" a Grid (which is called G). If you don't need that Grid out-parameter, remove it. Otherwise, do something to it in the body. Sounds like you need to spend a bit more time with a good book though, if you don't really understand the warning.

Answer (score 2):

I think you probably need to change `Grid_Load_LIF` to

```
procedure Grid_Load_LIF(Grille : out New_Grid ; File_Name : in String)
```

and then remove the line

```
Grille : New_Grid;
```

That way, when you say

```
grille.Largeur := Lu;
grille.Hauteur := Num_Ligne;
```

you're referring to the actual `New_Grid` passed by the caller of `Grid_Load_LIF`; that is, the caller will write

```
   Gr : New_Grid;
begin
   Grid_Load_LIF (Gr, "data_file.lif");
```

and on return `Gr` will hold the data read from the file.

Answer (score 1):

The basic issue here is that your subroutine contains an `out` parameter, `G`, which you never assign a value to. That means its value outside the routine, if the compiler allows you to do this, would be garbage (perhaps even causing a Contraint_Error).

**You need to give a value** (in all non-exception code paths) **for all your `out` parameters.**